# site slogan in h6 following h2 site name not matching WCAG 2.0 requirements

Tags: theming

Configuration : Drupal 7.26 / Omega 3 / Delta module
An accessibility check made with achecker.ca on a website gives me one result :

> Success Criteria 2.4.6 Headings and Labels (AA)
>   
>   Check 38: Header nesting - header following h2 is incorrect.
>   Repair: Modify the header levels so only an h3 or any header less than h3 follows h2.
>   Error Line 112, Column 7:

`<h2 class="site-name"><a href="/fr" title="website homepage"><span>for ...`

As I understand, it comes from the file : "sites/all/modules/delta/delta_blocks/includes/delta_blocks.theme.inc" 
The delta for the site slogan is defined as a h6, which doesn't match with WCAG 2.0 (AA) requirement :

> The header following an h2 is h1, h2 or h3

(http://achecker.ca/checker/suggestion.php?id=38).

So I might need to use a hook to change it, but I am such a newbie with hooks. I found this : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7 but it seems to hook the core module. Not very sure I want to do it.

Any help?

Comment: Sure it doesn't, but what's your question? It appears you want us to fix Omega theme for you. If that's the case, you're in bad place - it should be posted in Omega's issue queue instead.

Comment: well, no, I don't want anybody to do anything at my place.  The question was more about : does anybody had this issue and if yes or no, anybody could help me understanding if this is a Delta module issue or if there was a hook that I could use to fix it that I don't know about. So I'll look into the possibility to report it as an issue as you suggest and maybe patch it myself if I can. By the way I think it is very unappropriate to talk to me the way you do considering that we are on a place to ask for help, so maybe you are in the wrong place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hooks won't help you with this - the markup for the slogan is in the region--branding.tpl.php template file:

```
<h6 class="site-slogan<?php print $class; ?>"><?php print $site_slogan; ?></h6>
```

To fix, you can just create your own region--branding.tpl.php file in your sub-theme, and alter the markup to your needs.